# Using Background-Process to locate the User realtime in Flutter

Tags: flutter, background-process, geofencing

I want to track the users live position using Flutter while the App is not running. I found a Tutorial on Medium explaining how to do this but I could not wrap my Head around it neither get the sample code to run. Are there any samples Apps I can use to see how it is done using Background-Process or are there any other Ressources I could use to make this happen?

I already tried to follow a Tutorial explaining how to implement this using a Background-Process but the Sample could would not run.

I would like to monitor the live location and call a callback when the position changes.

Comment: Please post code snippet of what have you tried so far and share specific problems in order for others to help you

Comment: @daeh did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is the biggest limitation in Flutter, yet.

I've implemented a background service, but, I have to write all my way down in native code, and it's painful, I mean, it's painful if you don't have any experience in it.

The only way I managed to make a background service (to send push notification), and I believe, in your case, to track user's location, it's to find examples written in native code.